# can anybody say what does the pointer do?

Tags: c

this is my code I want to know what is happening here when we cast pointer?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int i = 22265484213,*pointer;
     pointer= &i;
     void *void_ptr; 
     void_ptr = &pointer;
     printf("\nValue of iptr = %d ", **(int *************************)void_ptr);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: What on earth is this supposed to be?

Comment: You will read a pointer from an address where only an `int` is stored. Then you provide this pointer to `printf` that expects to get an `int`. Welcome to *undefined behaviour*. Does your compiler give some feedback about that? If not, turn up warning level. For GCC this can be done using `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: You should also state what your current research effort is and what exactly is not clear to you?

Comment: I don't know if this will help you, but I'm going to try to make an analogy.  Suppose you work in a glass bottle manufacturing plant.  You notice that one of the bottles coming off of the assembly line has a hole in the bottom -- it's totally defective.  So you hit it with a hammer, to break it, so it won't accidentally get used.  Your friend asks, "When you hit it with a hammer, I don't understand why it broke into five pieces.  I would have expected it to break into seven pieces instead."

Comment: This program is like the useless bottle with a hole in the bottom.  And trying to understand "how this program works" is like trying to understand why the broken bottle broke into five pieces.  To me and most programmers, at least, it is totally uninteresting, totally meaningless, totally useless.  Almost every question you can possibly imagine about C would be more productive to investigate, more worth spending time on, than this one.

Answer (score 1):

It's an invalid pointer conversion. The point pointer is set to point at a `int**`, then you do an invalid conversion to the nonsense type with many stars, invoking undefined behavior. You would perhaps have gotten compiler messages here (invalid conversion, de-referencing type-punned pointer etc) but the `void*` suppresses them, which is a bad thing.

And then you de-reference the nonsense type 2 levels of indirection. One way the undefined behavior may manifest itself is printing the contents of the integer.

Also on normal real-world computers, `int` can't hold the value 22,265,484,213 so you would get an implicit conversion from a large integer type to `int` during assignment. It's likely that the code prints that converted value, for example `790647733` seems likely on 2's complement systems with 32 bit `int`. But again, the code has undefined behavior so nothing is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know what is happening here when we cast pointer?

The short answer is: Undefined behavior.

That is - the standard doesn't tell what exactly shall happen.

The C standard says that any pointer can be converted to a void-pointer and back to the **orginal** pointer type.

So this part:

```
void_ptr = &pointer;
```

is fine. As `pointer` is a pointer-to-int, `&pointer` is a pointer-to-pointer-to-int which can be converted to a void-pointer without problems.

But this cast

```
(int *************************)void_ptr
```

isn't converting the void-pointer back to the original type. Consequently, the conversion isn't defined by the C standard, i.e. undefined behavior - anything can happen.

The only valid cast would be:

```
(int **)void_ptr
```